# I got error on Metamask 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection'

Tags: javascript, svelte, web3js

I use svelte to create Web3 app and got some error

1.I already added web3.js cdn on my index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

2.this is my script on .svelte file to connect the Metamask Wallet

```
function connectWallet(){
if(window.ethereum){
  window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
  window.ethereum.enable();
  metamaskConnected = window.ethereum.isConnected();
  web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
    WalletAddress = accounts
    console.log(error)
  })
}
}
```

3. And when I open my website on the browser (Brave) for the first time I got this error

   > Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection

and the script not working

4. I have to refresh my page and then the error disappear so my code works normally

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same issue on my dapp, I've to investigate more but it looks like it happpen on any Chromium browser and ONLY IF clicking the dapp url open the browser in the same time.

Pretty weird bug, probably a problem between the communication of Metamask and Chromium browsers